# Cross-Domain Tracking Java Script Window.Location Redirect

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

We are using the code below on a site and find this is the only link on the site not adding in the session cookie data required for Cross-Domain tracking.  Any thoughts on how to get this link decorated properly so session data is passed between sites? I have checked GTM and everything is set up for cross-domain tracking properly, it is just the link being set with this I am having an issue with

```
$(function(){
    $(".book-now-button").off("click").click(function(){window.location = "URL"})
});
```